# Inject own name for test method into pytest output

Tags: python, testing, pytest

Normally pytest output for parametrized test method - `test_bar` of test class `TestFoo` looks like

```
path/to/test_file.py:67: TestFoo.test_bar[param1] FAILED
```

is it possible to inject own name based on parameter of `TestFoo` instance?

```
path/to/test_file.py:67: TestFoo.test_bar[own-generic-name] FAILED
```

Where `own-generic-name` is `str(self.baz)` of `TestFoo` instance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ids` keyword to pass a list of strings to `parametrize` in order to customize your test ids:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize('i', [1, 2], ids=['param1', 'param2'])
def test_foo(i):
    pass
```

Generates this output:

```
test_foo.py:3: test_foo[param1] PASSED
test_foo.py:3: test_foo[param2] PASSED
```

Customizing the generated ids by using a callable is being worked on [here](https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/pytest/pull-request/161) and looks like it will be merged soon.

Comment: Thank you, the possibility to pass a iterator looks promising. Btw, if I set `ids=[]` is it possible to access `ids` param later in `test_foo` to alter it, using the mutable nature of lists?

Comment: So I have tried to inject my own name which depends on `self` attribute with altering `ids=[]` and it didn't work, looks like pytest creates function names to output when collecting tests and doesn't change it later. Maybe some pytest hook magic will help me.